# Django URL trails other file URLs

Tags: python, django, url, slug

I'm building a website on Django. Here is the problem :

```
url.py : 
    url(r'^product/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', ProductView.as_view(), name='product'),
```

This URL calls product/product-slug successfully, but it affects other files' 
    urls. Error message is :

```
"GET /product/lenovo-tv/static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 4862
```

What am I missing?
    base.html :

```
<link href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="static/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="static/css/custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: It is an error with your template code, not your urls. Post your base template please.

Comment: your html is wrong. post your html for this page

Comment: _“What am I missing?”_ – only how relative URLs work ... When you are “on” the page `/product/lenovo-tv/`, and that page embeds a resource with the relative URL `static/css/bootstrap.min.css`, then of course this resolves to `/product/lenovo-tv/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`. Easiest solution: Use URLs that are relative to the domain root, so `/static/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Comment: How does it work? Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{% static 'css/custom-styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

in your html use the static files like this for `css` and `js`

Comment: hey mr downvoter, please give the reason before downvoting

Comment: Ah ha! Now I get what static_url in settings.py does. Thanks.